# Django template language unpacking a dict

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I have a dictionary passed (as part of another object) to the django template language.
The object, called 'poll' has attributes `self.text` and `self.votes`, where the former is a string, and the latter is a dict.
The dict, looks like this:
`{'a1': 45.92422502870264, 'a2': 53.50172215843857}`
I am trying to list each label, with its accompanying number, using the following:

```
{% for l, x in poll.votes %}
<p>{{ l }} {{ x }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Django responds with

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 3.
```

I tried `.iteritems` - The docs explain that `.iteritems` is not the correct way to do this, but they don't explain what the correct way *is*.

Comment: @Pythonista Thanks! Do you want to put it as an answer, and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just iterate the same way you would in python, but in Djangos templating language (DTL) syntax

```
 {% for key, value in dictionary.items %}
```

Your poll.votes is a dict but you're not iterating the items but the keys in your code.

You can find an overview of jinja [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/). Its worth noting that jinja isn't what django uses but its handy for a condensed reference since many things are the same (jinja is based upon DTL) instead of digging through djangos docs.

For Djangos tempaltes heres [the documentation reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/)

Answer (score 1):

you too can do this:

```
{% for variable in poll %}
   {{ variable.name }} - {{ variable.votes }}
{% endfor %}
```